# Unable to establish a connection to MongoDB AWS instance using MongoClient

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I am not able to establish a connection to mongodb which sits in aws instance using mongoclient library in java

```
public static final String MONGO_HOSTNAME = "mongodb://10.174.19.120:27017,10.162.45.16:27017/?replicaSet=rs0";
MongoClientURI mongoClientURI = new MongoClientURI(MONGO_HOSTNAME);
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(mongoClientURI);

    List<String> dbs  = mongo.getDatabaseNames();
    System.out.println(dbs);

    // Now connect to your databases
    DB db = mongo.getDB(MONGO_DB);
    long count = db.getCollection(COLLECTION_NAME).count();
```

I get the following error:

```
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting for a server that matches {serverSelectors=[ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}, LatencyMinimizingServerSelector{acceptableLatencyDifference=15 ms}]}. Client view of cluster state is {type=ReplicaSet, servers=[{address=10.162.45.16:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting}, {address=10.174.19.120:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting}]
    at com.mongodb.BaseCluster.getServer(BaseCluster.java:82)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getServer(DBTCPConnector.java:656)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.access$500(DBTCPConnector.java:40)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$MyPort.getConnection(DBTCPConnector.java:505)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$MyPort.get(DBTCPConnector.java:448)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:284)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:269)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.find(DBCollectionImpl.java:84)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:320)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:299)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:374)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.getDatabaseNames(Mongo.java:373)
    at com.myntra.apiTests.inbound.helper.MongoDBClient.get_mongo_db_count(MongoDBClient.java:25)
    at com.myntra.apiTests.inbound.test.InBoundTests.get_count_of_products_from_mongo_and_compare_with_es(InBoundTests.java:371)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:137)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main
```

Comment: Is the client able to connect to the mongods at all or is the security group setting to restrictive?

Comment: the client is not able to connect to the db.Manually it asks for the ldap credentials when i do an ssh to the mongohost which successfully authenticates and connects me to the db.